# Attaching a store with an Ext JS SplitButton or a Menu

Tags: javascript, extjs, store, extjs4.1

How can I attach a store with a SplitButton or a Menu?

I think the items associated with SplitButton & Menu are a good candidates for store. However I am unable to bring them together.

I'm using Ext JS 4.1.1

Comment: Nothing practically. Browsing the documentation of the said widgets as well as that of store. Also checked http://tinyurl.com/9k93skw but unable to correlate.

Comment: Have a look a [this](http://www.lubber.de/extjs/storemenu/)